# Array of dynamic length in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

EDIT:

Strictly speaking it's not a duplicate of the other question, but the accepted answer there can be used to solve my problem.

---

I would like to use an array that has length specified by a variable `n`, but once it is created, the length will never change.

In other words, something like

```
cin >> n;
int* a = new int[n];
```

is exactly what I want. But using `new` is a bit inconvenient, for mainly two reasons:

1. I have to remember to `delete[]` it in the end, possible leak of memory and the code gets longer;
2. When it comes to multidimensional arrays, the `new` process becomes rather complicated. For two dimensional, it will look like

   ```
   cin >> m >> n;
   int** a = new int[m];
   for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
       a[i] = new int[n];
   ```

   and even worse in higher dimensions.

I am aware that there is `std::vector` which can handle the first issue, but I think I still have to manually adjust the sizes of the vectors when creating multidimensional arrays. It also looks like an overkill, since I don't need to adjust the length after creation.

Also, I tried `std::array` and found that it doesn't accept variable lengths.

What I want is probably a hybrid, something like `myarray<class T, size_t N>` which allocates memory dynamically but only once. I can then use `myarray<myarray<T, m>, n>` to create multidimensional array.

So is there a good solution to this? Preferably I don't want to use a self-written wrapper template, but if there are no better solution then it's still acceptable.

Comment: You want std::vector

Comment: @AndyG But could you specify how do I use it to avoid adjusting the sizes manually? Maybe a short example for two dimensional arrays. Thanks!

Comment: vector<vector<unsigned>> myvec(depth, vector<unsigned>(depth,initialValue));

Comment: Consider using [Boost](https://www.boost.org/) or [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) framework libraries. You'll find something close to your needs. Or code your own `template<unsigned w, unsigned h, typename T> class mymatrix` thing which would represent internal data in some `std::vector`

Comment: @RobertEngel I see! This constructor solves the problem. If you post it as answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That won't work. The dimensions are only known at run-time, you can't use a template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vector<vector<unsigned>> myvec(depth, vector<unsigned>(depth, initialValue));
```

This will create a 2 dimensional vector of size depth*depth with the initial value `initialValue`